# Doesn't SteamPlay/Proton under AMDGPU-PRO work?

Tags: wine, steam, amdgpu, mesa

I'm new in LinuxGaming, switched from Win10 to Ubuntu 18.04 few weeks ago.

Now i found out how to use SteamPlay and Proton and i really like the idea!

But my problem is, that i can't start Games with SteamPlay under using AMDGPU-PRO.

My Main game is CS:GO, whichs works perfectly with amdgpu-pro, got 200fps in average.

So, i deinstalled all amd drivers and used mesa 19, now Steamplay Games working nicely, for example Skyrim Special Edition or Catan Universe, but my CSGO Frames droping down to 100 and when shooting and stuff under it goes under 60fps with really lags.

After installing amdgpu again, csgo works perfectly

Can someone help me? I really want to use Ubuntu further!

I am using RX480

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, RX-480 open source driver is already in the Linux kernel, and therefore installing and trying to use the AMDGPU driver is generally not necessary and can lead to problems down the line when kernel updates happen. You also used an updated MESA, which helps a lot in getting maximum performance out the open source driver.

Since you're asking specifically about CS:GO, why use Proton at all? After all, the game is available natively under Linux, so using Proton would not be necessary in this case, and you would likely get better performance by using the native version of the game. Valve's Proton exists in order to allow Windows games to run in Steam for Linux, but since CS:GO is native already, using Proton's compatibility layers would seem redundant.

Another thing that can help is using the latest stable kernel as possible, as driver updates come often and will help to maximize performance under the open source drivers. See, for example, [Using Ukuu To Keep Up With The Latest Mainline Kernels](https://kdedigest.blogspot.com/2018/03/using-ukuu-to-keep-up-with-latest.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the latest HWE kernel :

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Then depending on the game/application , you can add vulkan drivers

```
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers
```